# Compressing many similar small binary files independently using a preset dictionary

Tags: linux, compression, 7-zip

I have to compress many similar small binary packets (about 1.5 KB a packet) for data transmission. I tested `.xz` format on a 306 MB sample and I got 50% compression ratio (compressed to 153 MB). But when I split the sample into 1.5 KB pieces (packets) and compressed them independently, I can only get 1.3 KB archives. I believe that fewer duplicate fields in the 1.5 KB packet result in poor compression ratio. A reasonable idea is extracting and preset a big common dictionary for compression to approximate the case of a single large package. There's an explanation of preset dictionary:

> Preset dictionary can be useful when compressing many similar, relatively small chunks of data independently from each other. A preset dictionary should contain typical strings that occur in the files being compressed. The most probable strings should be near the end of the preset dictionary. The preset dictionary used for compression is also needed for decompression.
>                           — [Source](https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-javadoc/org/tukaani/xz/LZMA2Options.html#setPresetDict(byte[]))

But I can't find a way to implement the idea. To meet the compression ratio requirement, 62%, only LZMA based algorithms (`.xz`, `.7z`) can meet the requirement, and I just found a method to [set the preset dictionary](https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-javadoc/org/tukaani/xz/LZMA2Options.html#setPresetDict(byte[])), but I can't find any method to calculate/construct the dictionary, especially since the data are binary.

How can I calculate/construct the preset dictionary? Or is there a better idea to compress these small binary packets?

---

Clarification:
The data are generated 1.5 KB at a time
and need to be compressed and transferred immediately
instead of a single batch of many packets. 
It's real-time data and can't wait to be transferred in a batch. 
But I have a 306 MB sample of the packet data
to analyze the characteristics/patterns of the packets.

Comment: Do the packets need to remain separate files after compression, or will they just be transferred in a single batch anyway?

Comment: The packet is generated 1.5KB a time and needs to be compressed and transferred immediately instead of a single batch of many packets. Now I have a 306MB sample of the packet to analyze the characteristics.

Comment: Is concatenating the files to one file and then zipping it a solution?

Comment: No, the 1.5KB packet is generated per second, and I have to transfer 1.5KB packet immediately after it's generated. It's real-time data packet and can't wait to be transferred in a batch. But I have a 306MB sample that can analyze the pattern of the packet.

Comment: Can you use SSH and its compression for transport?